# Rabbitvcs not showing lock owner

Tags: svn, nautilus, rabbitvcs

I have installed rabbitvcs in my ubuntu 14.04 system. It's working well in it. But it's not showing the file lock owner when locking some already locked file. It just says failed lock.

As I show in tortoisesvn it's shows the user who has locked that file.

Here I am attaching screenshot also.
Please help me if any solution or alternatives are there for this problem.

[image: Rabbitvcs lock error!!!]

Comment: Anybody is there to help me??? Please give some way to overcome with this issue. Your help will be appreciable.....

Answer (score 1):

## SVN Status

You can check it by command :-

> $ svn status --show-updates

Output :-

> ```
> O   =   LockedFile 
> ?   =   UncommittedFile 
> M   =   ModifiedFile
> ```

After that fire this command :- 
To check lock owner Info,

```
$ svn info
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But dear I want solution for GUI, not for terminal. Please suggest me for it....

Comment: Seems there is no option available in GUI. Need to use command line only.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no options to get such info in rabbitvcs, I switch to esvn which is widely used in linux based environment.

It's working great than rabbitvcs.